# Making null values from array into averages of existing values

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, null

Ok, i have a random array with some values:

```
Integer[] array = {null,null,5,111,21,null,22,null,null,null,98,25,47,null,1,23,null}
```

I want to replace all the `null` values with averages of the nearest two existing array values.
For example: first two `null` values need to be replaced with the number `5` (`{null,null,5,...` becomes `{5,5,5,...`).

Next example: `{...,22,null,null,null,98,...}` should become: `{...,22,60,60,60,98,...}`; all three `null` values are to be replaced with average of `22` and `98` (`(22+98)/2`).

The last example: `{...,23,null}` should become `{...,23,23}`; `null` is replaced with `23` because it is the last element of the array.

Does anyone have an idea how to write an algorithm for this issue?

Comment: Why did you replace the first two nulls with 5 instead of with the average of the nearest two existing array values, which are 5 and 111?

Comment: @jwpat7: "two nearest" is to be understood as the 2 nearest values taken respectively on the left and right of the null value, I assume.

Comment: @haylem maybe, maybe not... The question is simply not clear enough.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. When the array starts with null values, you  replace them with the first existing value on the right, because it is not possible to calculate the average for null values if there are no existing value on the right AND left side of that null value. The nulls MUST have integer values on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take on it:

```
public static void fill(Integer[] newarr, Integer[] arr, int index) {
    if (arr[index] != null) {
        newarr[index] = arr[index];
        return;
    }

    Integer a = null, b = null;

    int i = index;
    while (i < arr.length - 1 && (a = arr[++i]) == null);

    i = index;
    while (i > 1 && (b = arr[--i]) == null);

    newarr[index] = (a == null) ? b : (b == null) ? a : (a + b) / 2;
}
```

Then:

```
Integer[] arr = { null, null, 5, 111, 21, null, 22, null, null, null,
        98, 25, 47, null, 1, 23, null };

Integer[] newarr = new Integer[arr.length];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    fill(newarr, arr, i);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newarr));
```

```
[5, 5, 5, 111, 21, 21, 22, 60, 60, 60, 98, 25, 47, 24, 1, 23, 23]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that this is done on `ArrayList<Integer>`:

```
//iterate over all values
for (int i=0; i<array.size(); i++) {
    //get the value at the current position
    Integer value= array.get(i);

    //if the value is null...
    if (value == null) {

        //find out the closes left and right values
        Integer leftValue= goLeft(array, i);
        Integer rightValue= goRight(array, i);

        //if both are integer values, find middle
        if (leftValue != null && rightValue != null) {
            array.add(i, (leftValue + rightValue)/2);

        //if left one is integer, and the other one is null? end of the array
        } else if (leftValue != null && rightValue == null) {
            array.add(i, leftValue);

        //if the right one is integer, and the left one is null? begin of the array
        } else if (leftValue == null && rightValue != null) {
            array.add(i, rightValue);

        //well, if everything is null, just add zeros
        } else {
            array.add(i, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

What is left for you is to implement

- `goLeft(ArrayList<Integer> array, int index)` and
- `goRight(ArrayList<Integer> array, int index)`.

I think they are pretty straight forward from the context and just by looking at their names.

Comment: I prefer not editing other people answers for such things that actually are not mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

1. determine all sequences of null (store start and end index
   of each sequence)
2. determine the border elements for each
   sequence and caclculate average (be sure to handle the extra cases
   start and end of array correctly)
3. replace the null by the
   calculated value

Answer (score -1):

A different possible, simpler but possibly less efficient solution:

1. for each null check left and right values
   a. if they are both numeric, take average
   b. if one is null and one is numeric, set the middle to the value, leave the other null
2. repeat until there are no nulls

**How does it work?**

```
{null,null,5,111,21,null,22,null,null,null,98,25,47,null,1,23,null}
{null,5   ,5,111,21,21,  22,  22,null,98  ,98,25,47,24  ,1,23,23  }
{5   ,5   ,5,111,21,21,  22,  22,60  ,98  ,98,25,47,24  ,1,23,23  }
```

The average of these values will be the same and the algorithm is simpler.

**Advantages**

- handles start/end nulls without any modification
- less memory required

**Disadvantages**

- does something a bit different...!
- may require multiple iterations
- in pessimistic case will take more time

Comment: Wrong algorithm: `22,null,null,null,98` should be replaced with `22,60,60,60,98` and not `22,22,60,98,98`. From OP: *"Next example: {...22,null,null,null,98...} should become: {...22,60,60,60,98...}"*.

Comment: @m0skit0 have you even read my post? I stated that in my answer.

Comment: You stated what exactly? That your answer is no answer to the question being asked?

Comment: @Dariusz: Not a bad idea, needs a little bit more work. Thanks for the effort!